# What does "seq_in_index" in MySQL database indexing means?

Tags: mysql, indexing, binary-tree, b-tree

[image: Index Results]
When an index is created, there is one column I have doubts about, in concern with the physical linking of the data nodes. 
When 2 "seq_in_index" are same, how are they placed in the node? How is the structure of the index binary tree in that case?

Comment: BTREE is not the same as "binary tree".

Comment: Do this: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`; it may be obvious what `seq_in_index refers to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the position of the column in the index.

Example:

```
INDEX some_idx(column_a, column_b)
```

`seq_in_index` for `column_a` is `1` and for `column_b` is `2`

In your case the compound index is

```
INDEX email(email, status)
```

Comment: Okay. I understand that. But what I do not understand is it's placement of nodes on same levels. So, in this case, primary and email is on the same level, so how is the structure of the node in this case. Are there two children for primary and email, OR are they grouped in the same nodes (which seems unlikely).

Comment: `PRIMARY` and `email` are two different indexes with two different BTREEs.